# How to add FirebaseUI to xcode (SwiftUI)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, firebaseui

I am new in iOS development and trying to use firebaseUI in my project.
I read documentation here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?authuser=0
but I can find anywhere in xcode that I can add firebaseUI.
I did add firebase-ios-sdk, but they are no firebaseUI inside.
The only one soure in firebase document said we have to add :

> pod 'FirebaseUI'

But I don't know where I can add this. Please help me deal with this issue. So much appreciate any help from anyone. Thank you !

Comment: That reference is for [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) you can follow the link and get more information. It is something you have to install on your Mac and then you will have to follow the Get started steps, once you have a `PodFile` in your project you can add that statement.

Comment: Thank @loremipsum, but I found some resource that we have to down xcode version to 12 to use it. Is there any way to use pod in xcode 13 ?

Comment: I don't think there is an Xcode 13 limitation, But I am not sure. I know M1 has issues but I think it works on Xcode 13 + an Intel Mac. I stoped using cocoa pods when I got my M1 so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: @loremipsum I am using M1 now and tried to use cocoapod but I got crash message when I used "pod install". I guess firebaseUI is not support for swiftui yet, the github for firebaseUI is in objectiveC and couldn't install for my project

Comment: @Stevie there's a nice discussion about this here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/811